# How to append ajax return data to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to append data to a table based on the ajax returned data.

My codes work but it seems ugly. I was wondering if anyone here can help me 
to simplfy it. Thanks a lot!

```
    ajax.callback=function(data){
          for (var i=0; i<dataObj[0].data.length; i++){
              var td=document.createElement('td');
              td.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i].ID;
              var td2=document.createElement('td');
              td2.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i].test;
              var td3=document.createElement('td');
              td3.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i].year;
              var td4=document.createElement('td');
              td4.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i].code;
              var td5=document.createElement('td');
              td5.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i].Label;
              var td6=document.createElement('td');
              td6.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i].contents;
              var td7=document.createElement('td');
              td7.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i].test;

              var tr=document.createElement('tr');
              tr.appendChild(td);
              tr.appendChild(td2);
              tr.appendChild(td3);
              tr.appendChild(td4);
              tr.appendChild(td5);
              tr.appendChild(td6);
              tr.appendChild(td7);


              $('#Table').append(tr);

           }
    }
```

Comment: Store your tr's as one dom fragment and do not append them until after the for loop. Other than that, it's not going to be less ugly without using a templating system or having your server return html.

Comment: Should you be using `data` and not `dataObj`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
ajax.callback=function(data){
    var elements = ["ID", "test", "year", "code", "Label", "contents", "test"];

    for (var i=0; i<dataObj[0].data.length; i++){
        var td;
        var tr=document.createElement('tr');

        for (var j=0; j < elements.length; ++j){
            td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i][elements[j]];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }

        $('#Table').append(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.createElement` and `innerHtml` is not very jQuery'ish. Why not just `td = $('<td>').html(dataObj[0].data[i][elements[j]);` ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar enough with jQuery to put stuff like that in. I was just showing him a way he could refactor his js in a js sense. If that's valid jquery, then by all means, make an answer with that instead.

Comment: Thanks so much, your code works except dataObj[0].data[i].elements[j] doesn't equal dataObj[0].data[i].ID

dataObj[0].data[i].elements[j] give me can't read property of 0 errro +1 though

Comment: @Rouge I made a little mistake in closing the [ bracket, so it may have been unclear. It's not .elements[j], it's [elements[j]].

Answer (score 1):

One (however not the most performant) of the more readable ways of doing this:

```
var tr = '<tr>\
    <td>{id}</td>\
    <td>{year}</td>\
    ...
    <td>{test}</td>\
</tr>';

tr = tr.replace(/{id}/, dataObj[0].data[i].ID)
    .replace(/{year}/, dataObj[0].data[i].year)
    .replace(/{test}/, dataObj[0].data[i].test);

$('#Table').append(tr);
```

Or use some templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ajax.callback=function(data){
    var keys=["ID","test","year","code","Label","contents","test"],
        tr=document.createElement('tr'),
        td=document.createElement('td');
    for (var i=0, li=dataObj[0].data.length; i<li; i++){
        var newTr=tr.clonenode(false);
        for(var j=0, lj=keys.length; j<lj; j++){
            var newTd=td.cloneNode(false);
            newTd.innerHTML=dataObj[0].data[i][keys[j]];
            newTr.appendChild(newTd);
        }
        document.getElementById('Table').appendChild(newTr);
    }
}
```

It's pretty much like CrazyCasta's answer, but cloning nodes is faster than creating them.